# Feasibility of transporting JavaScript and CSS as binary from server to client?

Tags: javascript, css, binary, compression, minify

I am a newbie in the web development field.

I see that minification of JavaScript and CSS is widely used to reduce web-page load times. But, undoubtedly, text format data will be longer than binary format, so why do we still use textual JavaScript and CSS?

Is it possible in the future to use binary format for servers to deliver presentational and behavioral definitions?

I think if there is a common standard to deliver these as binary data, then server-side programs will be created to convert text format JS/CSS produced by web designers to binary format, and network traffic will be greatly reduced.

Can anybody give me some ideas about this?

Comment: are there any articles that back up your claim that binary is better than minifying and gzipping?

Comment: @Joseph Hi Joseph, I just make this assumption on the basis that if we want to convey the same information "true", we might write "1" into the text file, if the text file is encoded as ANSI, it will weighs 1 byte, while only a single bit 1 into the binary file. I got a webpost which might be a bit topic-related: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/86383-q-text-vs-binary-files.

Comment: before you turn the internet into a big C program, you should better learn it's history what HTML was originally for and why it was text (hint: they call webpages "HTML **documents**") http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Markup_Language

Comment: @pinocchio, a binary format is useful only during *transport* of the file to minimize number of bytes for transmission over a slow link.  Gzip does this very well and there is probably not much gain by going to a straight binary format over a gzipped text format.  In your example, the letter "1" will be compressed by gzip to 1-bit if that's it is all duplicated in the file; as a matter of fact, a very large number which requires 64 bytes to store (which requires 64 bytes in a binary format) will still require 1 bit for gzip if it is all duplicated in the file.

Comment: Try some experiments and you'll find that gzip of a text format is typically not much larger than a compact binary format of the same representation.

Comment: @Stephen Chung I got what you mean. Then a more deep study of Gzip is certainly what I should do later. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Gzip is pretty widely deployed http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: Thanks for your link, but I didn't find anything related to my question. I am just wondering if it is possible to change the current standard of text format js and css into a binary one. I know a bit of Gzip things, but what gzip does is only compression, js is still "TEXT" js, and css is still "TEXT" css. Would it be better to use "BINARY" js and "BINARY" css?

Answer (score 3):

The feasibility is nil. It would require the existence of a universal standard for binary JavaScript and CSS, understood by all browsers, and by a lot of technology that is peripherally concerned with both.

There isn't one.

Comment: Yeah, I see there is not one for now. But is there any probability that this universal standard would come out?

Comment: @pinocchio Small but non-zero. There doesn't seem to be any demand for it. This is the kind of thing that gets overtaken by Moore's Law. It would provide a minor benefit at the cost of a lot of co-operative engineering, which is an extremely difficult feat in itself, and would be obliterated by a general doubling in network bandwidths. You should also remember the effects of caching. In short I would say the probability is vanishingly small.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that you didn't mention a binary version of HTML in your question.

A year ago, W3C published [EXI](http://www.w3.org/TR/exi/), a specification for binary XML. You can use XML to represent HTML documets, so it is already possible to represent HTML in binary in a standards-compliant way (however, browsers have yet to support this).

CSS is a very regular format, so creating a binary format for it wouldn't be hard. [(You might be interested in this.)](http://mainroach.blogspot.ru/2013/07/css-compression-binary-css-format.html) Standardizing that format, on the other hand, would be.

Maybe in the future, people will write all their code in abstraction languages like [SLIM](http://slim-lang.com/) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), which will then be compiled to binary XML, allowing browsers to use one very fast and efficient interface to parse both markup and style.

---

As others have pointed out, little effort is being spent on developing web standards for more efficient data transfer. The consensus at the moment is that binary formats will complicate things (it will no longer be possible to edit the data directly), won't reduce the size much more than *gzip**, and that further reduction in size is not necessary, especially since the introduction of fibre-optic.

<sub>* *gzip* is a general-purpose compression program much more widely used than any domain-specific binary format, and so is much more thouroughly tested and supported.</sub>